# Can android do "waitForResponse"

Tags: android

I am developing an application to communicate with a device via bluetooth.
Same as the BluetoothChat sample, my application makes a service object, and call service.connect() to get a connectedThread for data transmission.

and I have a command method, which takes an integer as its parameter.

the problem is, sometimes, that device returns invalid data.
So when I want to execute the command with ten different parameter, I need to do something like :

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myService.write(command(i)); 
    packet = waitForResponse(myService);

    if (packet is valid) {
        do something;
    } else {
        i--;
    }  
}
```

My program is using handler to deal messages, e.g. when the connectedThread read some data, it will

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(ControlActivity.MESSAGE_READ, -1, -1, data)
                         .sendToTarget();
```

And there is a handler in my Activity class to deal with these messages.

How can I do something like "waitForResponse" on Android?
or Is there any other way to meet my requirement?

API Level: 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting, run your activity normally and just listen from broadcasts from the service.

From the service class [send a global broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) when new data is ready, and have the activity class [listen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) and respond for that particular message.